# Small solutions of $f(x_1,...,x_n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

Let $f(x_1,...,x_n)$ be polynomial with integer coefficients.

Is the following possible:

For almost all primes $p$ exist integers $X_1,...,X_n$
such that:

1. $f(X_1,...,X_n) \ne 0$
2. $f(X_1,...,X_n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$
3. $\prod_i\max(1,|X_i|)=o(p)$ (small Oh on purpose)

Partial result over the integers $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1^2 + x_2^2$
and for about half the primes the solutions satisfy $X_1\cdot X_2 = O(p)$.
without using the congruence.

In case of positive answer, what is the best bound?

In case of negative answer, what are large subsets of primes satisfying the bound?

Comment: not sure the question is well written. It is known for every integer polynomial that is not divisible by a linear integer polynomial, there exist infinitely many primes $p$ for which the polynomial only has trivial roots. Hence, property (2) fails infinitely often.

Comment: For $O(p)$ and *all* $p$ take $f(X_1,X_2)=X_1(X_2^2+a)+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are any integers satisfying $a>|b|$. Then $f(X_1,X_2)=0$ does not have any integer solutions, but modulo every prime has a solution with $|X_1||X_2|=O(p)$ (take $X_2=1$ and then find $X_1$). Indeed, it may be the case that $|X_1||X_2|=o(p)$ can also be arranged this way, will try to check later today.

Comment: @Seva You need not worry about solutions over the integers if you don't use them in the congruences.

Comment: I do not understand; exactly what do you mean?

Comment: @Seva You wrote "does not have any integer solutions". I mean that you don't need this as long as you don't use it in the congruences.

Comment: I am afraid I am still missing your point. What do you mean "don't use it in the congruences"? If you do not care about integer solutions, then why not to take $f(X_1,X_2)=X_1-X_2$?

Comment: @Seva $X_1 - X_2$ Is not allowed to avoid triviality. Never mind this, probably I am wrong.

Comment: @Seva If you want you can take $f(x_1)=(x_1+1)(x_1-1)$. You are not allowed to set X_1 in {1,-1} but you can set it in {p-1,p+1}.

Comment: For all but finitely many $p$ that split over a field over which a *geometrically* irreducible component of the zero set of $f$ is defined, you can get $O(p^{ 1- 1/2n})$ unless the geometrically irreducible component is a linear subspace, using the Polya-Vinogradov method and Lang-Weil/Deligne.

Comment: "$X_i=X_1,\dots,X_n$" is very confusing notation.

Comment: @MaxAlekseyev Thanks for the critic. I changed the notation.

Comment: @ChrisWuthrich Thanks for the critic. I changed the notation.